# C++ list/queue top return value

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a C++ code as following :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>> q;
    q.push({8, 8});
    q.push({19, 19});
    q.push({23, 23});

    while (q.size() > 0){
        auto& cur = q.top();
        q.pop();
        cout << cur.first << " " << cur.second << " "; // returns 19 19 8 8 8 8
    }
    cout << endl;

    list<pair<int, int>> newq;
    newq.push_back({19, 19});
    newq.push_back({8, 8});
    newq.push_back({23, 23});
    while (newq.size() > 0){
        auto& cur = newq.front();
        newq.pop_front();
        cout << cur.first << " " << cur.second << " "; // returns 19 19 8 8 23 23
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Iterating over the `list` using `auto&` vs `auto` produces the same output. But I'm trying to understand why if I use `auto&` while iterating over the priority queue, the output is wrong. If I change it to `auto` my output is correct:

```
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>> q;
    q.push({8, 8});
    q.push({19, 19});
    q.push({23, 23});

    while (q.size() > 0){
        auto cur = q.top();
        q.pop();
        cout << cur.first << " " << cur.second << " "; // returns 23 23 19 19 8 8
    }
    cout << endl;
```

Thanks for any clarifications!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
auto& cur = q.top();
```

you are taking a reference to the top element in the `priority_queue`. But when you do:

```
q.pop();
```

this element is removed, and all references to it, including `cur`, are left dangling. Any attempt to read from `cur` e.g:

```
cout << cur.first << " " << cur.second << " ";
```

will invoke undefined behavior, which could do anything at all, including giving the results you observed.

---

Doing:

```
auto cur = q.top();
```

is fine, because you are making a copy of the top element. Removing that element from `q` doesn't affect the copy.

Answer (score 4):

```
    auto& cur = q.top();
    q.pop();
```

The reason why `auto &` does not work here and `auto` does, is because with `auto &` you get the reference to the object at the `top()` of the queue...

... and immediately, on the next line, that object on the top of the queue gets removed and destroyed, leaving you with a dangling reference.

Using that reference, from that point on, results in undefined behavior.

Using `auto`, instead, copies the object, and the copy continues to exist after the original object gets destroyed.

It is certainly possible that the analogous bug when used with `std::list` does not produce observably wrong results, but it's still undefined behavior. "Undefined behavior" means exactly that: anything can happen. Including getting the expected results, purely by accident. A good static analysis tool, like [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/), should be able to catch this bug.

Comment: But isn't the code assigning reference to the `top` in each iteration of the loop to `cur`?

Comment: No, it's not. `auto &` is a ***reference*** to another object. Not a copy of another object. `auto cur` is a full fledged object. `auto &cur` is a reference to some other object. What do ***you*** think is the difference between `auto cur` and `auto &cur`? `auto &cur=q.top()` is a reference to the object at the top of the queue. `pop()` destroys that object. It is no more. It ceased to exist. It's pining for the fjords. It's an ex-object. The fact that there was a reference to the object, somewhere, doesn't prevent it from getting destroyed.

Comment: ok I think I understand. But even then, I thought since I'm reassigning the reference in `cur` to `top` in each iteration, it should work without creating a copy of the pair. How do I get the actual object on `top` in `cur` without copying then?

Comment: @pranav3688 Just print `cur` *before* doing the `pop`. The reference will be valid until then.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik : I tried using Valgrind on this code. It does not catch this. But thank you!